# MPAndroid charting library, position of labels is getting messed up

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to put labels on a grouped bar chart, using the MPAndroid charting library, but am facing problems for quite some time now. I am using `axis.setValueFormatter()` function to set my labels. Here is my setValueFormatter function:

```
    public class MyAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter
    {
        private String [] m;
        public MyAxisValueFormatter(String[] arr)
        {
            this.m = arr;
        }

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
         //   Log.i("deep",Integer.toString((int)value));
            return m[(int) value];
        }

        @Override
        public int getDecimalDigits() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

And here is how I set my chart, machines is an arrayList which contains the labels:

```
    float barWidth = 0.50f;//0.45
    String[] mac = new String[machines.size()];

    for(int i=0;i<machines.size();++i)
    {
       mac[i] = machines.get(i);
    }

    BarChart chart1 = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    BarDataSet bds2 = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Target"); 
    BarDataSet bds1 = new BarDataSet(barEntries1,"Prepared");
    bds1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F44336"));
    BarData ddata1 = new BarData(bds1,bds2);
    chart1.setScaleEnabled(true);
    chart1.setPinchZoom(true);
    chart1.setData(ddata1);
    XAxis xa1 = chart1.getXAxis();
    xa1.setValueFormatter(new MyAxisValueFormatter(mac));

    xa1.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    chart1.setTouchEnabled(true);
    chart1.setDragEnabled(true);
    chart1.setScaleEnabled(true);
    float groupSpace = 0.0f;//0.08
    float barSpace = 0.0f; // //0.02   x2 dataset
    chart1.fitScreen();
    ddata1.setBarWidth(barWidth);
    xa1.setLabelCount(machines.size()+1,true);
    chart1.groupBars( 0.0f,groupSpace, barSpace);
    chart1.setFitBars(true); // make the x-axis fit exactly all bars
    chart1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    xa1.setGranularity(1f);
    xa1.setAxisMinimum(0);
    xa1.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xa1.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
    chart1.invalidate();
```

This is the screenshot of my charts with xa1.setLabelCount(machines.size(),true);

[scrot of chart with label count as machines.size()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBfvc.jpg)

As you can see the ANNE-LOSE label is missing.

This is how I populate my barEntries and machines arraylists. xa and xa1 were initialized to zero.

```
 barEntries.add(new BarEntry(xa++, Float.parseFloat(s)));
 barEntries1.add(new BarEntry(xa1++, Float.parseFloat(s)));
 machines.add(s);
```

Now there are two problems I am facing

1) The number of labels should be 5, but only 4 are displayed. The size of machines is five, I am sure of that.

2) If I increase the number of labels, the positioning of labels gets messed up. And as the setValueFormatter() function uses actual postions of the labels, my first label being on 0.0 and second on 0.95 both of them get typecasted to 0 and I get repeated labels.

So, I want to understand how these labels are positioned by the library. I printed the value of "value" variable in  MyAxisValueFormatter Class, in the logs. According to the documentation:

// "value" represents the position of the label on the axis (x or y)

[documentation link](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface)

(Updated Logs):

```
   07-26 11:08:23.560 19737-19737/com.example.quickstart I/flag: -0.5
07-26 11:08:23.561 19737-19737/com.example.quickstart I/flag: 0.5
    1.5
    2.5
    3.5
    4.5
07-26 11:08:23.571 19737-19737/com.example.quickstart I/flag: 0.0
07-26 11:08:23.572 19737-19737/com.example.quickstart I/flag: 0.95
    1.9
    2.85
    3.8
    4.75
07-26 11:08:23.576 19737-19737/com.example.quickstart I/flag: 0.0
    0.95
    1.9
07-26 11:08:23.577 19737-19737/com.example.quickstart I/flag: 2.85
    3.8
    4.75
07-26 11:08:23.578 19737-19737/com.example.quickstart I/flag: 0.0
    0.95
    1.9
07-26 11:08:23.579 19737-19737/com.example.quickstart I/flag: 2.85
    3.8
07-26 11:08:23.599 19737-19737/com.example.quickstart I/flag: 0.0
07-26 11:08:23.600 19737-19737/com.example.quickstart I/flag: 0.95
    1.9
    2.85
    3.8
    4.75
07-26 11:08:23.602 19737-19737/com.example.quickstart I/flag: 0.0
    0.95
    1.9
07-26 11:08:23.603 19737-19737/com.example.quickstart I/flag: 2.85
    3.8
```

Below are the correct values of various arrayLists.

Here are the values of barentries:

```
0000004548,0000002784,0000004331,0000002166,0000005569
```

barentries1:

```
000000000002041,000000000002041,000000000001887,000000000000798,
000000000004947
```

machines:

```
TEMP-3,TEMP-1,BENTLER-1,DEMAN,ANNE-LOSE
```

After changing xa1.setLabelCount(machines.size(),true) to xa1.setLabelCount(machines.size() + 1,true), I get the following result:

[scrot of chart with label count as machines.size()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhPZk.jpg)

The first value get repeated twice, but now I get the desired number of labels(five labels), just the wrong ones. I have also updated the actual number of labels and the barentries and the log values accordingly. Mind you I am getting data from a live source therefore the data keeps changing this is the new data I am posting.

If someone understands how the charting library works please explain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: machines.size() is an array, so if size is 12, i think that for this line in specific you should use  xa1.setLabelCount(machines.size() + 1,true); try it and let me know, and also show how you populate your barentries

Comment: I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Sry I couldn't help you with that, I'm quite sure that isn't a library error and is just a error in one for where your set up barentries, I've using this library for two weeks (For LineChart and Piechart) and had no issues so far, also I never had to use setLabelCount att